# Magento 2 Transactional E-mail template engine. How it works?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

In the order email template I need to do a if..else statement, but I don't know how to do it.

Below a template code snippet:

```
<table style="margin:0 auto;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:750px;background:#fff">
    <tbody style="margin:0;padding:0 77px;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">
    <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">
        <td style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0">
            <div style="margin:0;padding:0 77px;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">
                <h2 style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#737373;font-size:14px;font-weight:300;line-height:1.6em;padding-bottom:20px">Oi <span style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#005c82;font-weight:bold">{{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}}</span>!</h2>
                <p style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#737373;font-size:14px;font-weight:300;line-height:1.6em">A sua compra foi confirmada com sucesso! <br style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">
                    saiba que estamos imensamente felizes por você ter adquirido um ahimsa =)</p>
                <p style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#737373;font-size:14px;font-weight:300;line-height:1.6em;padding-top:20px">Veja aqui os detalhes do seu pedido:</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The variables are accessed as below:

```
{{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}}
```

So, how to do if...else statement?

```
{{ if something=='test' }}
  {{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}}
{{ endif }}
```

I tested:

```
{{if payment_html=="itaushopline"}}
     <p style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#737373;font-size:14px;font-weight:300;line-height:1.6em">ou copie e cole a linha digitável no seu banco</p><p style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#8fcf61;font-size:14px;font-weight:300;line-height:1.6em">{{var order.getPayment().getAdditionalInformation('linha_digitavel')}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

But did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can  use the if condition like following Example:

```
{{if order.getCustomerFirstname == 'test'}}
     <p>{{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this to work...it seems that it compares only booleans and not string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right @Diego .
You can use condition like this

```
{{if logo_width}}
    width="{{var logo_width}}"
{{else}}
    width="200"
{{/if}}
```

please review [magento doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html)

Comment: I update my question. Tried your answer but did not worked.